# If I were adding multiple attributes to different entities in Magento, would I use a different setup model for each?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've written a module that adds an attribute to the customer model, and it's worked fine.

I wanted to extend the `sales/order_shipment` model and add another attribute, so I just used the same reference that I had used for the installer for adding the new customer attribute.

I relied on Magento finding and installing the module a file with the following path and name `app/code/local/[namespace]/[module_name]/sql/install-01.php`

I've set the installer to the value of `$this` during the setup of the module initially:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
```

I kept the same reference for the installer and just added a new field:

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer','sap_bp_id',
    array(
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'label'             => 'SAP Business One Business Partner ID',
        'input'             => 'text',
        'required'          => false,
        'visible'           => true,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'global'            => 1,
        'position'          => 62,
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute('shipment','sap_doc_num',
    array(
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'label'             => 'SAP Business One Document Number',
        'input'             => 'text',
        'required'          => false,
        'visible'           => true,
        'visible_on_front'  => false,
        'global'            => 1,
        'position'          => 62,
    )
);
```

It's worked just fine, but I want to know this:

Is this the correct method for adding a new attribute for different models in the same installation file?  Is there a better method?  Have I missed anything?